# Can I change a user field with twig without using a form?

Tags: templating, users, form, custom-fieldtype, custom-field

I basically just want to set the value of a users field to a different number if something happens, so that the user field is actually updated in the CMS. Can I do that without creating a form? So like if I had a custom user field I wanted to update in twig and actually have it change the data in the CMS. I know you can do this with a user/save-user form, but I don't really want a form for this because I don't want it to actually be changed by the user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's possible via the special Twig [`do`](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/do.html) tag, which basically enables you to call methods without returning (i.e. outputting) anything (which is what happens with nearly every other Twig expression).

Assuming the "users field" is a custom field attached to the users' field layout (and you've got a `user` variable in your Twig template referring to a [User](https://docs.craftcms.com/api/v3/craft-elements-user.html#public-properties) element), something like the below should work:

```
{% do user.setFieldValue('fieldHandle', 123456) %}
{% do craft.app.elements.saveElement(user) %}
```

What the above does, is first setting the custom field value for a field with the handle `fieldHandle` to a value `123456` on the `user` element, via the [`setFieldValue()`](https://docs.craftcms.com/api/v3/craft-base-element.html#public-methods) method (which is available for all Craft element types). Then, the user is (re)saved using the [`Elements::saveElement()`](https://docs.craftcms.com/api/v3/craft-services-elements.html#public-methods) method (which is what Craft uses to save elements under the hood).

In PHP, the same thing would look like this:

```php
$user->setFieldValue('fieldHandle', 123456);
Craft::$app->getElements()->saveElement($user);
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Sorry to hijack - is it possible to create a user in this way?

Comment: @iamkeir Technically yes, I think so. Probably not a good idea, in any case it’s going to be difficult to really answer in a comment so you should probably create a new question for it :)

Comment: @MatsMikkelRummelhoff ah the old "just because you can, doesn't mean you should" :) yeah I'll post a new question, thanks.

Comment: For anyone interested, specific query about creating a user: https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/39591/create-user-in-twig-without-form